# How to debug an issue happening only when a (google) bot requests a page?

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, httprequest

My application is throwing a `Zend_Locale_Exception` when called from googlebot where ZF sends the following error message:

> Autodetection of Locale has been failed!

The problem is probably because the default locale isn't set, but how can I debug this?

Since google bot isn't real time I need to actually forge the HTTP Request the bot is making, but how can I find out how this request is being made?

Trying to send the **Accept-Language** header  with curl wouldn't reproduce the error:

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mysite.com.br/');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language'));
   echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
```

**EDIT:**

to clarify even further:

- I Know the issue is probably the lack of a default locale, but **I NEED to debug this**
- Changing the user agent of my browser doesn't work, it only changes the UA string, the Locale is still sent from my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Fetch as Googlebot" feature in Google Webmaster Tools. You might be able to use this to trigger the bot hitting your site. You could even temporarily add a `phpinfo()` page to your site and use the feature to hit that, which will list all the headers in the response that it shows you.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is:

- **Always set a default locale**, so if auto-detection fails, a locale will be used by default anyway.

In order to do so, you can add in your *application.ini*:

```
resources.locale.default = "en_US"
```

Also, make sure you don't use the detected locale in your bootstrap, if you have to do it, always ensure that the locale resource has been *"boostrapped"* using `$this->bootstrap('locale');` in the methods/plugins that use `Zend_Locale`.

You can simulate the same behavior using a terminal and a browser such as Lynx, then you would probably need to unset some environments variables (like *LANG*, *LANGUAGE*).

Comment: yes, as i said this is problably the issue, but how can you confirm this since it's happening only in google?

Comment: Ofc GoogleBot doesn't crawl websites through a browser. This user agent doesn't use _Accept-Language_ header when it crawls your website.

Comment: changed the question to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

wget --user-agent "googlebot(at)googlebot.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "http://www.mysite.com.br/"

Comment: as specified, merely changing the UserAgent won't return the same data since the Accept-Language header is still being sent

Comment: just dive into curl parameters and check exactly what headers you are sending. ie: curl -I http://mysite.com.br etc..

Answer (score 1):

There can be numerous reasons why you see the exception, so you can not just "test" this. When you need to test against the googlebot request, you must store the request so that you can replay it later against your webserver.

However, as written, there can be numerous reasons this is triggered, you find the autodetection in [`Locale.php`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/zend-locale/blob/master/Locale.php#L1022).